# Opposite override on PHP

Tags: php, class, overriding

There are too many child classes and I want to handle them if they contains 'e.g.' getName() function and override them in a 'Super Class' and want to print 'a' for each of them. How can I implement this?

```
<?php
   class SuperClass{
      public function getName(){
          echo 'a';
      }
   }
   class ChildClass extends SuperClass{
      public function getName(){
          echo 'b';
      }
   }
   class SecondChildClass extends SuperClass{
      public function getName(){
          echo 'c';
      }
   }
$a = new ChildClass();
$a->getName(); //prints a
$b = new SecondChildClass();
$b->getName(); //prints a
?>
```

Comment: You can call parents function like: `parent::getName()` in `getName()` function.

Comment: I dont want to call parent::getName() for each of child class.

Comment: In that case you can pass optional parameter to define you want to call parent function or not.

Comment: @ActuallyMAB why ? it saves code from redefining the same function over and over again..

Comment: or don't include getName() in the child classes and they'll use the parent's version automatically

Comment: @GeoPhoenix because of these classes are entities that generated from Doctrine ORM for each of my tables and I dont want to edit them.

Answer (score 4):

For your example, to work correctly just remove the getName() function from the SuperClass. If you still want to call the SuperClass getName every once in a while try overloading the SuperClass getName function.

getName($flag)

That way if you want to class the SuperClass variable you pass it the flag otherwise it will call the child class.

```
<?php
   class SuperClass{
      public function getName($flag){
          echo 'a';
      }
   }
   class ChildClass extends SuperClass{
      public function getName(){
          echo 'b';
      }
   }
   class SecondChildClass extends SuperClass{
      public function getName(){
          echo 'c';
      }
   }

   $a = new ChildClass();
   $a->getName(); //prints b
   $a->getName(true); //prints a
   $b = new SecondChildClass();
   $b->getName(); //prints c
   $b->getName(true); //prints a
?>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work in PHP 5.4.4: _Strict Standards:  Declaration of ChildClass::getName() should be compatible with SuperClass::getName($flag) in ..._ And it just prints `bbcc`.